# pd.merge not performing as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I've got two tables, referenced as df (internal dataset) and ibos (externally sourced data). Both datasets are about a shared vocabulary of five levels where df contains id numbers and ibos contains the id numbers and the names belonging to these numbers.

Example:

df (4590 records): `chapternumber,articlenumber,subarticlenumber,instrumentnumber,detailnumber,60_more_columns`

ibos (4610 records): `chapternumber,chaptername,articlenumber,articlename,subarticlenumber,subarticlename,instrumentnumber,instrumentname,detailnumber,detailname,amount`

Sample data can be downloaded here: [df](https://www.gitlab-minfin.nl/uploads/checkTotals_0a_df.csv), [ibos](https://www.gitlab-minfin.nl/uploads/checkTotals_0b_ibos.csv).

What I would like to do is to only merge in the names from the ibos dataframe into df such that the number of df records stays the same, simply that they are enriched with the names belonging to the id numbers.

Like so:
df (4590 records):
`chapternumber,chaptername,articlenumber,articlename,subarticlenumber,subarticlename,instrumentnumber,instrumentname,detailnumber,detailname,60_more_columns`

It sounds pretty straightforward but I can't seem to figure it out. My attempt was:
(nummer = number, naam = name)

```
df = pd.merge(
  df, 
  ibosdata[['nummer_hoofdstuk', 'nummer_artikel', 'naam_artikel_ibos', 'nummer_artikelonderdeel', 'naam_artikelonderdeel_ibos', 'nummer_instrument', 'naam_instrument_ibos', 'nummer_detail', 'naam_detail_ibos']], 
  on=['nummer_hoofdstuk', 'nummer_artikel', 'nummer_artikelonderdeel', 'nummer_instrument', 'nummer_detail'], 
  how='left'
)
```

Unfortunately, this statement produces [this](https://www.gitlab-minfin.nl/uploads/checkTotals_1_merge.csv) dataframe of 6437 records and not the desired same 4590 records.

What should I change in my merge statement to only import the names belonging to the id numbers?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Can you list (in your question) specifically which columns you want from each dataframe? It's not clear from the code you've posted, mostly because `on` does not take a list as an argument, so it's unclear what your actual goal for that list of columns was.

Comment: This is because the combination of the joining keys in either `df` or `ibos` - `['nummer_hoofdstuk', 'nummer_artikel', 'nummer_artikelonderdeel', 'nummer_instrument', 'nummer_detail']` are not unique (e.g. multiple rows may have the exact same values for all these columns), and hence the number of rows are duplicated in a join. You may wanted to deal with such duplicates before doing the merge

Comment: @kelvt You were very much correct! There was another column that needed to be added to make everything unique. Doing that resulted in exactly the desired number of rows.